# Cannot solve NG Error: bad argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting an angular error and need some help!
Link to error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=LoginCtrl&p1=not%20a

```
"Error: ng:areq
Bad Argument
Argument 'LoginCtrl' is not a"
```

I have been working on this for some time now and cannot find what I am doing wrong here. I have researched this error and my scripts are correct, I believe my functions are correct syntax wise...I tried to take ng-view out and put it in another partial, this fixed my error issue but broke my game.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Memory Game</title>
    <!-- <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="344924208843-lr7f74mh6q2j9sn3kadb5i93m6ne6pnd.apps.googleusercontent.com"> -->
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">

    <div ng-include="'partials/navBar.html'"></div>

    <body ng-app="MemoryGame">

    <div class="ng-view">

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src= "lib/node_modules/angularfire/dist/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>



    <!-- My Stuff -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/factories/authFactory.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/factories/gameFactory.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/controllers/LoginCtrl.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/controllers/ProfileCtrl.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/controllers/DashboardCtrl.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

LoginCtrl.js

```
'use strict'

app.controller("LoginCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope,$location, $window,firebaseURL, authFactory) {

  let ref = new Firebase(firebaseURL);

  if($location.path() === "/login") {
    ref.unauth()
  };

$scope.login = () => {
    authFactory
      .Googlelogin($scope.account)
      .then(function(stuff) {
        $window.location.assign('/#/profile');
      })
    };
});
```

app.js

```
'use strict'

var app = angular.module("MemoryGame", ["ngRoute"])
  .constant("firebaseURL", "https://memapp.firebaseio.com/");

let isAuth = (authFactory) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if(authFactory.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log("User is authenticated, resolve route promise");
    resolve();
  } else {
    console.log("User is not authenticated, reject route promise");
    reject();
  }
});


app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    templateUrl:'partials/userProfile.html',
    controller: "ProfileCtrl"
    // resolve: {isAuth},
  }).
  when('/login',{
    templateUrl:'partials/login.html',
    controller:"LoginCtrl"
  }).
  when('/profile',{
    templateUrl:'partials/userProfile.html',
    controller:"ProfileCtrl",
    resolve: {isAuth},
  }).
  when('/dashboard',{
    templateUrl:'partials/dashboard.html',
    controller:"DashboardCtrl",
    resolve: {isAuth}
  }).
  otherwise('/')
});
```

profileCtrl.js

```
'use strict'
app.controller("ProfileCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, $location,$timeout,firebaseURL, gameStorage){

let matches = [];
let moves = 0;
let score = 0;

//an array of objects for cards
$scope.cards = [
  {id :"card1",isFlipped:false, emojPics:"../data/Emoji-Poop.png", value:0},
  {id: "card2",isFlipped: false, emojPics:"../data/Emoji-facePlant.png", value:1},
  {id: "card3",isFlipped:false, emojPics: "../data/Emoji-Whatever.jpeg", value:2},
  {id :"card1",isFlipped:false, emojPics:"../data/Emoji-Poop.png", value:3},
  {id: "card2",isFlipped: false, emojPics:"../data/Emoji-facePlant.png", value:4},
  {id: "card3",isFlipped:false, emojPics: "../data/Emoji-Whatever.jpeg", value:5}
];

//setting display/username to root scope
$rootScope.loggedInUserDisplayName = "";
console.log("rootScope validated");

//checks for number of cards clicked
function checkRound(card) {
  moves += 1
  console.log("number of moves ",moves)
  if (moves <= 2){
    isFlipped(card);
    console.log("does this trigger a 2nd time? ");
  }
  else if(moves > 2) {
    console.log("More than 2 Moves");
  }
};
```

AuthFactory.js

```
app.factory("authFactory", function(firebaseURL,$rootScope) {
  let ref = new Firebase(firebaseURL);
  let currentUserData = null;
  let isNewUser = true;

  return {

  Determine if the client is authenticated through firebase

    isAuthenticated () {
      let authData = ref.getAuth();
      //if statement if user is authenticated or not
      return (authData) ? true : false;
    },

    getUser () {
      return currentUserData;
    },


//Authenticate the client via Firebase

    Googlelogin(){
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ref.authWithOAuthPopup("google", function(error, authData) {
          console.log("auth error", error);
          if (error) {
          console.log("Login Failed!", error);
          reject();
          }else{
          console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:",
           authData);
          $rootScope.username = authData.google.displayName;
          resolve(authData);
          }
        })
      })
    },

  Store each Firebase user's id in the `users` collection

    storeUser (authData) {
      let stringifiedUser = JSON.stringify({ uid: authData.uid });

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $http
          .post(`${firebaseURL}/users.json`, stringifiedUser)
          .then(
            res => resolve(res),
            err => reject(err)
          );
      });
    }
  };
});
```

gameFactory.js

```
'use strict'
app.factory("gameStorage", function($q, $http, firebaseURL, authFactory){

var getGameList = function(){
        let games = [];
        let ref = new Firebase(firebaseURL);
        let authData = ref.getAuth();
        let user = authFactory.getUser();
    return $q(function(resolve, reject){
      $http.get(`${firebaseURL}games.json?orderBy="uid"&equalTo= "${authData.uid}"`)
        .success(function(gameObject){
          var gameCollection = gameObject;
          Object.keys(gameCollection).forEach(function(key){
            gameCollection[key].id=key;
            games.push(gameCollection[key]);
            console.log("gameCollection",gameCollection);
              });
            resolve(games);
              })
            .error(function(error){
            reject(error);
        });
    });
  };
//
//   var getSingleGame = function(gameId) {
//     console.log("gameId",gameId);
//     return $q(function(resolve, reject){
//       $http.get( firebaseURL + "games/"+gameId+".json")
//         .success(function(gameObject){
//           resolve(gameObject);
//         })
//         .error(function(error){
//           reject(error);
//         });
//     });
//   }
//
//  var deleteGame = function(gameId){
//     return $q(function(resolve, reject){
//       $http
//         .delete( firebaseURL + `games/${gameId}.json`)
//         .success(function(objectFromFirebase){
//             resolve(objectFromFirebase);
//         });
//     });
//   };
//
//     var postNewGame = function(newGame){
//         // let user = authFactory.authData.displayName
//         // console.log("user",user);
//         let ref = new Firebase(firebaseURL);
//         let authData = ref.getAuth();
//         // console.log("authData",authData);
//         console.log("uid", authData.uid);
//             return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
//                 $http.post(
//                 firebaseURL + "games.json",
//                 JSON.stringify({
//                     uid: authData.uid,
//                     timeLeft: newGame.timeLeft,
//                     matches: newGame.matches
//                     })
//                 )
//             .success(
//                 function(objectFromFirebase) {
//                     resolve(objectFromFirebase);
//                 });
//         });
//     };
//
//
return{postNewGame:postNewGame,getGameList:getGameList,deleteGame:deleteGame,getSingleGame:getSingleGame};

});
```

Comment: Can you post the full url that you get with the error?

Comment: Yes, @MikeFeltman here it is: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=LoginCtrl&p1=not%20a

Comment: That looks truncated. Usually angular will give you more than that.

Comment: Show the code for `ProfileCtrl`, at least the first few lines

Comment: Everything in the code you have posted looks OK. I suspect something is trying to reference LoginCtrl before it's defined. Does authFactory.js or gameFactory.js reference LoginCtrl?

Comment: @MikeFeltman You were right, I was referencing my LoginCtrl in app.js before it was defined. Once I commented out that reference my error went away. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If `ProfileCtrl` is in a file `profileCtrl.js` with a lower case "p". It's likely the file isn't being loaded due to case sensitivity of the `<script>` reference in `index.html`.

change:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/controllers/ProfileCtrl.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/controllers/profileCtrl.js"></script>
```

Or try changing the name of the file from `profileCtrl.js` to `ProfileCtrl.js` to match the `<script>` reference.

**Update:**

In regards to your other [error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=authFactoryProvider%20%3C-%20authFactory%20%3C-%20LoginCtrl), I think it's the same case sensitivity issue occurring with the `AuthFactory.js` file reference in `index.html`. That file isn't being loaded and that is why the `Unknown Provider` error. is occurring

Change:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/factories/authFactory.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/factories/AuthFactory.js"></script>
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Well, I got a new error so that's a good thing!
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=authFactoryProvider%20%3C-%20authFactory%20%3C-%20LoginCtrl

Good eye!!

Comment: No problem, it can be finicky, glad to help!

Comment: See my updated answer, I think the same case sensitivity issue exists for your `AuthFactory.js` file. You are referencing `authFactory.js` in the `index.html` with a lowercase "a", it should be uppercase to match the filename.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem exists here:

```
<div ng-include="'partials/navBar.html'"></div>

<body ng-app="MemoryGame">
```

You have angular code included outside of the ng-app inclusion.

I would recommend either attaching the ng-app="MemoryGame" to the html tag or bringing the ng-include inside of the body. which should be the case in html regardless.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I will play around with this...I am still getting this injector error
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=authFactoryProvider%20%3C-%20authFactory%20%3C-%20LoginCtrl

I think I have a good start on this! Thanks again for your help!